# DB Design for subsystem context - KVP vs columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

In complex systems, is it quite common to have generic sub-systems that relate to several entities.  An example might be a workflow engine where a Requisition, Job and Assessment might each have their own workflow.

Some might even have >1 link to a sub-system, such as a forms engine, where a user might have a personal details form, and employee history form.

You could even consider logging to be a sub-system, where an entity could have multiple log records.

There are a couple of ways model this "context", one is using KVP style:

CREATE TABLE Workflows (WorkflowID, ContextObject varchar(20), ContextKey int ), where ContextObject would contain either 'Job', 'User', 'Assessment' and ContextKey would be either the JobID, UserID, AssessmentID, etc.

Another way is using wider tables with nullable columns, eg,

CREATE TABLE Workflows (WorkflowID, JobID INT NULL, UserID INT NULL, AssessmentID INT NULL )

Where the context keys are mutually exclusive.

I'm wondering which approach is "better" from a performance point of view, especially as row counts increase around the hundreds of thousands to millions?

The KVP style table will end up with narrower rows (larger table), with the nullable-column approach having wider rows, however individual indexes can be built over those rows. Using SQL Server, we can use Filtered Indexes to create an index for each context, where the contextID is not null.

Using the nullable-column approach would result in better statistics available to the optmizer - ie, if it's a join based on JobID, then the optimzier would know that of the 1 million rows in that table, only 10,000 relate to jobID.

I'm wondering what peoples thoughts are on the two different approaches.

Assume that each of the contexts provides a fairly high cardinality (almost 1 for each context type.) Also assume a recent version of SQL Server.